# Is there an elegant built-in way to work with aliases?

Tags: applescript

The only ways I know so far are

```
(path to documents folder as string) & "foo.txt" as alias
```

which feels more like a work around (by consecutively changing types), and

```
choose file of (path to documents folder)
```

which is far more elegant, but it demands manual choosing.

Comment: An alias is not text, so if you want to add text to it it needs to be coerced to text.  Text is not an alias, so if you want it to be an alias it needs to be coerced to an alias.  What are you wanting to do?

Comment: The only way you know to make the alias, is the most effective (fastest) way as well. So, I suggest to continue with it. You can coerce System Events file to alias directly, but coercing file to alias is slower than coercing text (HFS) to alias: **tell application id "sevs" to set anAlias to (file "foo.txt" of documents folder) as alias**. You can test, it is slower.

Comment: Following works 2 times faster: **tell application id "sevs" to (path of documents folder & "foo.txt") as alias** than my last example, but still slower than your original code.